# Serializing nested documents mongoDB to Jackson

Tags: java, json, mongodb, serialization, jackson

so I am using Jackson (together with Mongojack) to create POJO's of MongoDB Documents. My database looks something like this:

```
Document{ id:1, Document2{ value1:1 value2:2}}
```

I have created a POJO for Document, and for Document 2, and this generally works fine. The problem is that some places in my Database, Document2 has a value of NaN instead of being a nested document with several values, which leads to this error

```
ERROR [2015-07-21 16:01:26,809] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 3b38d500d7657352
! com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.document1.document2] from Floating-point number (NaN); no one-double/Double-arg constructor/factory method

!  at [Source: de.undercouch.bson4jackson.io.LittleEndianInputStream@534093c6; pos: 1975] (through reference chain: com.document1["document2"])
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
```

Not really sure what the best way to go about fixing this is. I guess what I'd want is for Jackson to recognize if Document2 is just :nan instead of a nested document, and just serialize it with no values or something?

Answer (score 0):

It's really best if you can keep the data you're working reasonably consistent. That said, there may be a way to hack around this:

```
public class Document2 {

    public Document2() { }

    public Document2(double invalid)
    {
        System.out.print("invalid");
    }

    public void setValue1(int value1)
    {
        System.out.println("value1 " + value1);
    }

    public void setValue2(int value2)
    {
        System.out.println("value2 " + value2);
    }
}
```

In the "happy" case, Jackson will use the default constructor and set the properties as given. In the `NaN` case, it will find the single-argument double constructor, and leave the other properties alone.